# Extending Trix using rails actiontext with your favorit css icons set e.g. font-awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, trix, actiontext

I am using rails action text --> trix.

I would like to extend trix with a button where the user can choose from a preset / selction of icons / smilies which are already included in the website stylesheet e.g. font-awesome.

Does anybody has an idea how to accomplish this?